# scipy.misc.imresize not working in GCP ml-engine

Tags: python, scipy, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm trying to submit the following toy snippet as a job in GCP ml-engine:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc

x = np.zeros([10, 10, 1])
y = scipy.misc.imresize(x[:, :, 0], [50, 50, 1], interp='nearest')
print(y)
print(y.shape)
```

It is giving the following error after the job starts on server:

```
File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/teste/test.py", line 6, in <module>
y = scipy.misc.imresize(x[:, :, 0], [50, 50, 1], interp='nearest')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imresize'
```

It works perfectly on local, and according to Cloud-ML docs, the scipy package is supported. Apparently it is not an issue with the module itself, as the import statement is not giving any error.

Comment: When you use ml-engine, you have to build a package using a setup.py file. Try adding a dependency to scipy (using the 'install_requires' field of the setup function).

Comment: Actually just adding scipy is not enough, you have to add pillow as the accepted answer stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scipy.misc.imresize` requires PIL to be installed, which you probably have installed locally (since it works).

To ensure your code runs correctly in the cloud, you need to ensure `pillow` is installed. If you have created your own `setup.py` include `pillow` in the list of requirements. If you have to create your own, create a `setup.py` like this:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['pillow']

setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='My trainer application package.'
)
```

([source](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/packaging-trainer#to_include_additional_pypi_dependencies), with one important modification, the `packages` attribute)

See the official CloudML Engine [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/packaging-trainer#to_include_additional_pypi_dependencies) for more information about recommended directory layout and packaging instructions.

Comment: It is curious that it is not required to add scipy to install_requires to use some of its functions, I tried calling scipy.misc.factorial without adding scipy and it was working.

Comment: Apparently it is not clear in the documentation which modules are implicitly made available and which requires a explicit install_requires, even though they are stated as available in the runtime image

Comment: This case is particularly confusing because the image manipulation functions in scipy.misc require PIL, but scipy doesn't install PIL. The CloudML environment does include scipy but not PIL. For a list of what is already installed, see https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/concepts/runtime-version-list

Answer (score 1):

It was deprecated in 1.3.0.
Contrary to using Pillow, reinstall scipy 1.0.0

```
pip install scipy==1.0.0
```

Or

```
pip3 install scipy==1.0.0
```